# RCP Application could not be found in the registry after exporting

Tags: eclipse, rcp

Hello friends I am getting this following error when i launch my eclipse rcp application as product on linux machine

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-08 04:37:14.171 !MESSAGE The
>   following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see
>   the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists: !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-08 04:37:14.171 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   com.spundhan.eboard.project_1.0.0.201211071703 [5] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 com.spundhan.eboard.project 2 0 2012-11-08 04:37:14.172
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.500.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-11-08 04:37:14.173 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.RuntimeException: Application
>   "com.spundhan.eboard.project.application" could not be found in the
>   registry. The applications available are:
>   org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.app.error,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool.
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

Answer (score 3):

The bundle `com.spundhan.eboard.project` which probably contains your application could not be resolved because of a missing dependency. It seems the bundle `org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal` is not part of you product. Adding it to your product configuration should fix this problem.